# How to get binary string of a pixel C#

Tags: c#, image

I am working on a simple project that involves changing the binary data of several pixels from a bitmap. I was simply wondering how to print the binary data of one specific pixel to the console. I have written some basic code here lets say myBitmap is already an image:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);


Color pixel = myBitmap.GetPixel(1, 1);
```

How can I print the full pixel binary data or say just the 8 bits of either RGB, is this possible

I presume there are pixel. methods that may acheive this?

Comment: You just want the RGB values?  or the A value as well?

Comment: @maccettura Just the RGB but in binary?

Comment: Do you want 24 bits? (8 R 8 B 8 G)

Comment: The [`.R`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.r(v=vs.110).aspx), [`.G`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.g(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`.B`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.b(v=vs.110).aspx) properties of returned [`Color`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color(v=vs.110).aspx) object are all of type `byte`.  That should give you everything you need.  If you want a binary _string_ representation of that data then just use `Convert.ToString(pixel.R, 2)` and that will give you a base2 string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Color`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color(v=vs.110).aspx) struct has 3 properties you can use to your advantage:

- [`.R`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.r(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`.G`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.g(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`.B`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.b(v=vs.110).aspx)

These properties are all of type `byte`.

If you want a binary *string* representation of that data:

```
//Converts to base2 and left pads '0' to a maximum of 8 positions
// for a "pretty" binary byte representation
string binaryStringR = Convert.ToString(pixel.R, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
```

If you want to make this more reusable, I would suggest an extension method:

```
public static string GetBinaryString(this byte input)
{
    return Convert.ToString(input, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
}
```

This will allow you to get the "pretty" binary string representation of any byte by doing:

```
string binaryString = someByte.GetBinaryString();
```

I made a fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pJpMXe) to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that will give you an array of 3 elements containing the binary format of R, G then B:

```
public static string[] ColorToBinary(Color color)
{
    string[] binary = new string[3];

    binary[0] = ByteToBinary(color.R);
    binary[1] = ByteToBinary(color.G);
    binary[2] = ByteToBinary(color.B);

    return binary;
}


private static string ByteToBinary(byte b)
{
    return Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
}
```

To use it:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
Color pixel = myBitmap.GetPixel(1, 1);
string[] binary = ColorToBinary(pixel);
// binary[0] = binary form of pixel.R
// binary[1] = binary form of pixel.G
// binary[2] = binary form of pixel.B
```

Comment: Well apart from the "g" I missed which you could've just pointed out, yes It did work.